# Show item options in Cartthrob order email

Tags: cartthrob

I'm trying to get Item Options to show in Cartthrob's order email. I'm using the code from the documentation but it doesn't seem to work;

```
{exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="{entry_id}" }
    <tr class="{item:switch="odd|even"}">
        <td><span style="font-size:12px;">{item:entry_id}</span></td>
        <td><span style="font-size:12px;">
            {item:title}
                <p>
                    <span style="font-size:9px;">
                {item_options}
                     <strong>{option_label}</strong> {option_name}: {option_value}
                {/item_options}
                </span>
                </p>
            {if is_package}
                <p>
                    <span style="font-size:9px;">
                {packages}
                    {sub:title}<br /> 
                {/packages}
                </span>
                </p>
            {/if}
            </span></td>
        <td align="right"><span style="font-size:12px;">{item:quantity}</span></td>
        <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="right"><span style="font-size:12px;">{item:price}<br />(w/ tax: {item:price_plus_tax})</span></td>
        <td align="right">
            <span style="font-size:12px;">
                {item:subtotal}<br />(w/ tax: {item:subtotal_plus_tax})
            </span>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            {if item:product_download_url}
            <span style="font-size:12px;"><a href="{exp:cartthrob:get_download_link field='product_download_url' entry_id='{item:entry_id}'}">Download</a></span>
            {/if}
        </td>
    </tr>
{/exp:cartthrob:order_items}
```

The item options are definitely captured because when I view the order entry it shows all the selected options.

Has anyone else had this trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to modify your template next way:

```
         {item_options}
             {if selected}<strong>{option_label}</strong> {option_name}: {option_value}{/if}
        {/item_options}
```

Comment: Hmm, weird. It works now. Heh. Maybe it's 'cause I'm on an older version. Got a question for you though to follow up about a database error with MX Google Map on the eec.ms forum. :P